# How to make sure that users may enter 0 in either field but not both

Tags: javascript

I need to validate the fields below, users can enter 0, but not in both fields, and neither one of the fields can be empty.

I am trying to do this:

```
if((document.getElementById("NumberOfOpenings").value.trim() == "" || document.getElementById("NumberOfOpenings").value.trim() == 0) && (document.getElementById("NumberOfEntrances").value.trim() == "" || document.getElementById("NumberOfEntrances").value.trim() == 0)) {
// instruct user to only enter 0 in one but not both fields, and make sure field is not left black.
} else {
    // carry on
    }
}
```

Could I get some basic help on this question? Does the code look correct?

Thank you

Comment: Anything not working with the given code?

Comment: Calling `document.getElementById().value` over and over again to validate is cumbersome. Instead place all your values to variables then do your comparisons on those.

Comment: What will you do if the user enters a NaN? You should probably treat that as having the same response as the field being empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add in some custom form validation logic.

Here is an example of a form where either field may be submitted. Since I made the `<input>` element a `[type="number"]` input, empty values are not allowed.

```js
document.forms['CustomForm'].addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);

function validateForm(form) {
  const errorMessages = {};
  const openingsInput = form.elements.NumberOfOpenings;
  const entrancesInput = form.elements.NumberOfEntrances;
  if (!isValidNumber(openingsInput) && !isValidNumber(entrancesInput)) {
    errorMessages['NumberOfOpenings'] = 'Both fields should not be empty!';
  }
  if (!isNonZero(openingsInput) && !isNonZero(entrancesInput)) {
    errorMessages['NumberOfOpenings'] = 'A zero may only be present in one field!';
  }
  return errorMessages;
}

function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target;
  const openingsInput = form.elements.NumberOfOpenings;
  const errorMessages = validateForm(form);
  for (let field of form.elements) {
    const groupEl = field.closest('.input-group');
    if (!groupEl) {
      continue;
    }
    const errorMessageEl = groupEl.querySelector('.error-message');
    const errorMessage = errorMessages[field.name];
    groupEl.classList.toggle('has-error', errorMessage != null);
    errorMessageEl.textContent = errorMessage ?? '';
  }
  if (Object.keys(errorMessages).length === 0) {
    console.log('Success!');
    //form.submit();
  }
}

function isValidNumber(numberInput) {
  return !isNaN(numberInput.valueAsNumber);
}

function isNonZero(numberInput) {
  return numberInput.valueAsNumber !== 0;
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

.input-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

.input-group:has(input[required]) label:after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}

.input-group.has-error input {
  border-color: red;
}

.input-group input {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group .error-message {
  display: hidden;
  color: red;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.input-group.has-error .error-message {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" name="CustomForm">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="no-op">Number of Openings:</label>
    <input type="number" id="no-op" name="NumberOfOpenings" value="0" required />
    <span class="error-message"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="no-en">Number of Entrances:</label>
    <input type="number" id="no-en" name="NumberOfEntrances" value="0" required />
    <span class="error-message"></span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make the code easier to read by copying the values into variables so you don't have to keep writing the verbose calls to `getElementById()`.

Then you can combine the 3 conditions.

```
let numOpenings = document.getElementById("NumberOfOpenings").value.trim();
let numEntrances = document.getElementById("NumberOfEntrances").value.trim();

if (numOpenings === "" || numEntrances === "" || (numOpenings === "0" && numEntrances === "0") {
    // report validation error
} else {
    // process values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the id´s on variables and using else if

```
let numberOfOpeningsValue = document.getElementById("NumberOfOpenings").value.trim();
let numberOfEntrancesValue = document.getElementById("NumberOfEntrances").value.trim();

        if (numberOfOpeningsValue === "" || numberOfOpeningsValue === 0 ) {
        // Logic When numberOfOpeningsValue has an empty value and numberOfOpeningsValue is equal to 0
    } else if (numberOfEntrancesValue === "" || numberOfEntrancesValue === 0) {
       // Logic When numberOfEntrancesValue has an empty value and numberOfEntrancesValue is equal to 0
    }
    else if (numberOfOpeningsValue === "" || numberOfOpeningsValue === 0) {
        // Logic When numberOfOpeningsValue has an empty value and numberOfOpeningsValue is equal to 0
    } else if (numberOfEntrancesValue === "" || numberOfEntrancesValue === 0) {
        // Logic When numberOfEntrancesValue  has an empty value and numberOfEntrancesValue  is equal to 0
    } else {
        // Carry on
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to me more like a approach problem rather than JS help. So, Here is a simple easy to understand code (pseudo code almost) where there is a error thrown based on the values entered or not.

```
value1 = getRef(1stField); // document.getElementById("NumberOfOpenings").value.trim();
value2 = getRef(2ndField); // document.getElementById("NumberOfEntrances").value.trim();

function notEmpty(value){
  if(value !== null && value !== undefined)return true;
  return false;
}

// validate returns true if validated otherwise throws error
function validate(){

  if(notEmpty(value1) && notEmpty(value2)){
    if(value1 == 0 && value2 === 0)throw Error("both can't be zero");
  }else{
    throw Error("Need both values");
  }

  return true;
}
```